# How do I send an authorization token via the header using beforeRouteEnter in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, router

I'm trying to send an authorization bearer token before a user tries to access the "/" endpoint and I'm using the beforeRouteEnter navigation guard provided by Vue Router to do it. In the "/" route on the backend, the "Authorization" header is undefined, although there have been a few instances where the token was sent but I couldn't determine why it was successful those few times. I console logged the headers and can verify that the header was updated properly from the front end.

```
{
    path: "/",
    name: "home",
    component: HomeView,
    beforeRouteEnter: async (to, from, next) => {
      const auth = getAuth();
      auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
        if (user) {
          api.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = user.accessToken;
          console.log(api.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"])
          next();
        } else {
          next({ name: "login" });
        }
      });
    },
  },
```

I am making the API call in the HomeView component on mount by dispatching an action like so:

```
//HOMEVIEW COMPONENT

  mounted() {
    this.$store.dispatch("getData");
  }
```

```
//store

 actions: {
    getData({ commit }) {
      return axios("http://localhost:7002/").then((res) => {
        commit("updatePosts", res.data.posts.rows);
      });
    },
```

Comment: Here you are only setting the header. This code seems fine at first glance. The relevant code you need to show is when the actual api call is made and details regarding the when and how that call is triggered.

Comment: @MatJ I have updated the question to include that code

Comment: What is `api` vs `axios`?